# (Java) Finding all possible combinations of an array of numbers

Tags: java, recursion

I'm writing a program in Java that creates all possible combinations of a given amount of numbers.
For example, if you have an array of {1,2,3,4}
I need to write a program that creates all possible combinations following the formula 2^(Array.length)
given that I have 4 numbers, my total possible combinations is 2^4 = 16.
A sample output would be

```
{} {1} {1,2} {1,2,3} {1,2,3,4} {2} {2,3} {2,3, 1} {2,3,4} {3} {3,1} {3,1,4} {3,4} {4} {4,1} {4,2}
```

the concept is identical to a truth table like (F,F,F,F) (F,F,F,T) (F,F,T,T) etc.

I've tried a number of things with loops and recursions but just cant seem to get it, and I'm feeling like an idiot so any help would be very appreciated

what I have so far

```java
public class PractiveProblem9 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "1234";
        permute(s.toCharArray(), 0);
    }

    public static void swap(char[] array, int i, int j) {
        char temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }

    public static void permute(char[] array, int n) {
        if (n == array.length - 1) {
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(array));
        }
        for (int i = n; i < array.length; i++) {
            swap(array, n, i);
            permute(array, n + 1);
            swap(array, n, i);
        }
    }
}
```

output so far is

```
1342
1432
1423
2134
2143
2314
2341
2431
2413
3214
3241
3124
3142
3412
3421
4231
4213
4321
4312
4132
4123
```

Comment: have you tried to write something till yet? please share your written code.

Comment: I uploaded what I had so far

Comment: What if you counted from 0 to 2^n-1 and used each of the n bits in each of the numbers in that sequence to decide whether to include each of the n numbers in your list.

Comment: Hint: assume you have all possible subsets of the elements 2..n. You then get all possible subsets of the elements 1..n by taking these and another copy where you add element 1 to each subset.

Comment: Does this help? [Overview of Combinatorial Problems in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-combinatorial-algorithms)